# How to create a super thin border ( black ) around a border that is super thick and multi color

Tags: css

I would like to add a super thin black border 
over and below the border in this ring.

http://jsfiddle.net/PUBqA/5/

the goal is to make this ring easy to see 
on a white background.

the only way to do that would be to add some thin
black border outside the ring and inside the ring.

this is the code i have so far:

css:

```
#ring{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border:100px solid black;
    border-color: red blue green yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="ring"></div>
```

Comment: borderception. why not use an image of the circle instead of creating it in css?

Comment: @user986959, photoshop is expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add like this in your code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PUBqA/10/)**

```
#ring{
   box-shadow:0 0 0 10px #000, 0 0 0 10px #000 inset;
  -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #000, 0 0 0 10px #000 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #000, 0 0 0 10px #000 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #000, 0 0 0 10px #000 inset;
}
```